# Is there a way to split column separated by special character and allign to respective values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below

```
df
ColA  ColB  ColC
A     x|y    a|o
B     h|g    k|l
```

Is there way to split it below

```
df1
ColA   ColB  ColC
A       x     a
B       y     o
A       h     k
B       g     l
```

Basically it is one to one match separated by "|"

Can we achieve this?

Comment: `df.assign(ColB=df['ColB'].str.split('|'), ColC=df['ColC'].str.split('|')).explode(['ColB', 'ColC'])`